# Если поля Input не заполнены, то сделать свойство кнопки disabled

Tags: jquery, события

Всем привет. Нужно решить следующую задачу, сразу скажу что jquery изучаю на начинающем уровне.
Есть 3 input для ввода обычных данных.

-ФИО

-EMAIL

-ТЕЛЕФОН.

Есть кнопка, которая отправляет на сервер форму. Так вот как сделать так, если поля Input не заполнены то у кнопки есть свойство disbled. Т.е. Он не даст отправить форму. Если заполнены все то кнопка становиться активной и отсылает форму.

P/s/ В данном случае алгоритм я уже придумал,!

После того как фокус пропал с поля input я проверяю пустое оно или нет. Если не пустое то я прибавляю к какой нибудь переменной 1. В конце я проверяю если это переменная равна 3 (в моем случае 3 инпута) то я делаю кнопку активной. Я незнаю на какие события это сделать в jquery?

Comment: @duddeniska, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно навесить на onchange каждого input функцию которая будет проверять заполненность полей.

Вот сделал для данного примера решение - http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/2/

Comment: поправил ссылку